# Warning: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, ios9, xcode7

I am getting this warning after updating Xcode to Xcode 7 while i am hitting this request for Google AdWords given by google AdWords SDK.

```
[ACTAutomatedUsageTracker enableAutomatedUsageReportingWithConversionID:kGoogle_ConversionAppUpdateID];
[ACTConversionReporter reportWithConversionID:kGoogle_ConversionAppUpdateID label:kGoogle_ConversionAppUpdateLabel value:kGoogle_ConversionAppUpdateValue isRepeatable:NO];
```

On googling i am getting the answer to update info.plist as iOS 9 and OSX 10.11 require TLSv1.2 SSL for all hosts. So already updated it as given below [image]

But i am still getting this warning. I don't have clue what else i should do, so all answers are appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code of your HTTP request?

Comment: @Lorenzo i have just update my question so that you can see the request.

Answer (score 3):

i recommend you add this keys into your info.plist file in your project

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
 <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
 <dict>
 <key>YourDomine(google.com-- without https or ...)</key>
 <dict>
 <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
 <true/>
  <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
   <string>TLSv1.1</string>
  </dict>
       </dict>
     </dict>
```

**UPDATE** 
relate this Link you can resolve your problem :
you can add this keys :) 
[iOS 9 Considerations](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/ios9?hl=en)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
 </dict>
```

Comment: i am getting this error on using Google AdWords SDK so not able to get the requesting domain url

Comment: @GauravPandey please tell me about your result

Comment: @MohamadFarhand Thanks for your effort;  but it also doesn't help. as u see i in my question i am already add this in my plist.